# apple wireless keyboard and bootcamp boot screen

Tags: boot-camp, wireless-keyboard

I have to hold ALT key of my keyboard to boot mac pro in windows. but using wireless keyboard it doesnt work when computer starts up, and it directly boots in mac osx. is there any workaround on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the startup disk via System Preferences on the OS X side, or the Boot Camp control panel on the Windows side.

Comment: ok but the problem is in macos bootcamp cp windows 7 partition doesnt appear, win was installed via bootcamp on a different internal disk, somehow it doesnt apeear in bootcamp

Comment: macos also cant mount it with macfuse and ntfs 3g

Comment: Something's wrong with your install then.  The things you listed above should work.